# Show $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x-i) \cong \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x+i) \cong \mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ring-isomorphism

We have to show $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x-i) \cong \mathbb{C}$

Lets consider $\psi: \mathbb{C}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ define $f(x) \mapsto f(i)$. Then  $\psi$ is ring homomorphism as $\psi(f(x)+g(x))=f(i)+g(i)=\psi(f(x)+\psi(g(x)) \ \text{and} \ \psi(f(x)(g(x))=f(i)g(i)=\psi(f(x))\psi(g(x)) \ \text{and} \ \psi(1)=1$

$\psi$ is onto as if $a+ib \in \mathbb{C}$ then there exists $f(x)=a+xb \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ suchthat $\psi(f(x))=f(i)$

Now $ker \psi=\{f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]| f(i)=0\}=\{f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]| \text{now} \ f(x)=(x-i)q(x)+f(i) \ \text{but} \ f(i)=0 \ \text{so} \ f(x)=(x-i)q(x)\}=\{f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]| f(x)=(x-i)q(x)\}=(x-i)$

So from first isomorphism theorem $$\mathbb{C}[x]/(x-i) \cong \mathbb{C}$$

Now to show $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x+i) \cong \mathbb{C}$ we just take the map $f(x) \mapsto f(\bar i)$ where $\bar i=-i$and all the process is same as just above. Is it okay?

Comment: This is just fine Nothing special about either $i$ or $-i$. The evaluation homomorphism works this way for any element in any field.

Comment: @EthanBolker so you are saying we just need $f(x) \mapsto f(i)$ to show both isomorphisms

Comment: No. For any fixed $z$ the evaluation map $f(\ ) \to f(z)$ induces the isomorphism you want. It's a different map each time.

Comment: @EthanBolker Okay got it

Comment: You can directly use the fact that any polynomial has $i$ as a root if and only if $(x-i)$ divides it. It is due to the fact that $(x-i)$ is irreducible and also a prime element of the Euclidean Domain of $\Bbb{C}[x]$ .

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok, except for you did not define $a,b$ in the second paragraph.
I would improve it like following:

$\psi$ is onto $\mathbb{C}$ because for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ there exists (a constant function) $f(x)=z \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ satisfying $\psi(f(x))=z$

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are defined by using $a+bi$ as the representation of an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{C}$. The proof could be improved by mentioning the implied $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.